# Uncaught (in promise) CompileError: wasm validation error: at offset 4: failed to match magic number. simple wasm app with javaScript

Tags: javascript, webassembly, wasm-bindgen

my  index.html as:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <h1>WebAssembly Addition App</h1>
    <p>Result: <span id="result">0</span></p>
    <button onclick="add()">Add 1 + 2</button>
    <script src="add.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

then add.js as:

```
async function add() {
  // Load the wasm module
  const wasmModule = await WebAssembly.compileStreaming(fetch('add.wasm'));
  const wasmInstance = await WebAssembly.instantiate(wasmModule);

  // Call the "add" function in the wasm module
  const result = wasmInstance.exports.add(1, 2);

  // Update the result on the page
  document.getElementById('result').textContent = result;
}
```

also my add.wasm as:

```
(module
  (func $add (param $x i32) (param $y i32) (result i32)
    (i32.add (get_local $x) (get_local $y)))
  (export "add" (func $add)))
```

Now, I run `npx http-server` in the same folder of all those files. got this error message visiting the localhost index page

```
add.js:11 Uncaught (in promise) CompileError: WebAssembly.compileStreaming(): expected magic word 00 61 73 6d, found 28 6d 6f 64 @+0
await (async)
onclick @ (index):5
```

What should I do to solve it?

trying to get mini wasm working with javaScript in the browser with localhost.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might have wrong expectation with what the function `WebAssembly.compileStreaming` does. It seems you are expecting it to compile the source code in *WebAssembly Text Format* into a WebAssembly JavaScript module. Especially, your file `add.wasm` contains WebAssembly Text Format, and should therefore be called `add.wat`.

The `WebAssembly.compileStreaming` will transform a webAssembly module into a JavaScript module, so you need first to transform your `add.wat` file into a proper `add.wasm` - which is a binary format. to do that, you can use the utility `wat2wasm` using the WebAssembly binary toolkit (https://github.com/WebAssembly/wabt) or some online tool such as http://mbebenita.github.io/WasmExplorer/.

Once you have your wasm ready (and by-the-way you will need to replace those non-standard `get_local` statements by `local.get`) everything should work fine.